# How to clean felt pen ink from the wall?

Tags: cleaning, paint, home, house-cleaning

I have a paper on the wall where I used to write with felt pens. Another day, I accidentally left a wet rag hanging over it. I did not realize until now that the rag soaked both the paper and the wall as at present, I have dry pen ink on the wall.

Since I am renting this apartment, I require some cheap solution or hacks to clean it up and I did not want to risk anything so that it could not go even worse.

I tried with a wet sponge but realised that paint on the wall is very thin and the stain is not going away....Please help providing me any hacks for this.

Answer (score 2):

If the ink has soaked into the paint, it *might* be possible to make the mark lighter with a bit of chlorine bleach, but that could also damage the paint, so try the bleach on an inconspicuous spot, e.g. inside a closet.

If you can find the exact color of the paint, it might be possible to cover the mark... but it might be easier and cheaper to let the owners know, since they may have kept paint for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that might be the case. If I tell the owners, can they cover just that one part of the wall or do they have to paint the entire wall over again (it's white)?

Comment: Honestly, it depends on the paint and condition, and the owner. If the paint is a dull (chalking) latex, it probably will match well, if the surrounding area hasn't yellowed. Most leases leave the tenant at the mercy of the landlord, but my own experience as a tenant has been that landlords are not out to cause bad will. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you the following:

- Before going for a similar kind of paint, try applying a white non-gel toothpaste. Apply it and let it remain for some minutes, don't rub and spread out the mark onto other parts of the wall. Wipe from outside of the spot to inside with a clean cloth.
- Try to get a thick cotton absorbent towel, apply some alcohol and try holding onto the spot so that the ink gets absorbed onto the towel.